# Add a gem to the bundle without adding it the Gemfile (rspec + fuubar)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundle, bundler

I use "fuubar" as a formatter of my choice to the RSpec. In my `~/.rspec` I got `--format Fuubar` line, which means in any RSpec run, in any project (regardless of Gemfile content) `--format Fuubar` is used.

I don't want to add this as a dependency to the project, as it is a very personal thing and in some projects, you as a team decided to keep your Gemfile slim without unnecessary gems.

How to run RSpec with `--format Fuubar` without adding Fuubar gem to your Gemfile?

The error I get after running `rspec` without fuubar installed:

```
/Users/filip.bartuzi/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- fuubar (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [bundler config](https://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html) you can add your custom `Gemfile.local` which will inherit all dependencies from the project `Gemfile`.
Body of `Gemfile` should be similar to bellow one:

```
# Gemfile.local
eval_gemfile "./Gemfile"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'fuubar'
end
```

Then before your `bundle` command, you should pass environment variable `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.local`. Which would result with the following command:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.local bundle exec rspec --format Fuubar spec
```

*don't forget to run `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.local bundle install` before*

Comment: Having `Gemfile.local` automatically loaded would make a nice feature for bundler.

Comment: I like this solution in principle, but it produces gem incompatibility issues when I run `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.local bundle install`, even though `bundle install` works fine. Haven't worked out why yet.

Comment: Incompatibility issues above resolved by copying `Gemfile.lock` to `Gemfile.local.lock` before running `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.local bundle install`. Suggests our Gemfile needs an overhaul ...

Comment: @AndyB Even copying of lock before `bundle install` may update your project dependencies (if the additional development gem requires different versions). Proper locking in your `Gemfile` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'd install it using `gem` command:

```
gem install fuubar
```

Note that if you use different versions of ruby or different gemsets per project, you'll need to install that multiple times (once per version/gemset).

Comment: This does not work. `gem install fuubar` succeeds, but when you run `bundle show fuubar` it returns `Could not find gem 'fuubar'`

Comment: also: `bundle exec gem install fuubar` does not solve the issue

Comment: It's not added to the bundle (Gemfile.lock), but it's present in your installed gems

Comment: it still causes `require': cannot load such file -- fuubar (LoadError)` Did you try it yourself?